# Lambda expression returning values for two foreign keys and passing them to view (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have two tables:

```
Language (
    int LangId,
    string LangName
)

Dictionary (
    int DictId,
    string DictName,
    int LangFromFK,
    int LangToFK
)
```

I want to return dictionaries which name starts with 'a' (this is easy) but instead of `int` values for foreign keys I want to have names of appropriate languages. Such a list I want to send to view- what kind of `@model` should I have for the `view`?

How can I do it?

Comment: `How can I do it?` by starting writing some code and then ask here if you get stuck.

Comment: I got stuck at a very start. Please give me a keyword/hint how to start with `FKs` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
var query =
    from d in dictionaries
    where d.DictName.StartsWith("a")
    join fl in languages on d.LangFromFK equals fl.LangId
    join tl in languages on d.LangToFK equals tl.LangId
    select new
    {
        d.DictId,
        d.DictName,
        LangFrom = fl.LangName,
        LangTo = tl.LangName,
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

What your trying to do is possible. Foreign keys are commonly associated with the primary key of another table. Usually the primary key is an auto incrementing int column. However, foreign keys can be linked to any column so long as it has a unique constraint.

> A foreign key constraint does not have to be linked only to a primary
>   key constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

Referenced from [Create Foreign Key Relationships - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx)

So in order for you to place a foreign key on the `LangName` you will have to apply a unique constraint on that column in your database. In order to do this, the best answer will come from the .NET documentation. The [DataColumn.Unique Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.unique(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good starting point.

Comment: Sorry but it does not seem to answer my question.

Comment: This answer is way off base. The OP is asking to join on the integer fields and return the `LangName`. He doesn't need to do any database changes.

Comment: @Enigmativity Am I missing something from this? `"but instead of int values for foreign keys I want to have names of appropriate languages"`.

Comment: @KirillFuchs - He just wants to join on `LangId` and return `LangName`.